# resize-img module expected `buffer` to be of type `Buffer` but received type `object`. Logging argument returns buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-resizing

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Expected `buffer` to be of type `Buffer` but received type `object`
push../node_modules/resize-img/index.js.module.exports

```js
let pathi = fs.readFileSync(path.join(this.props.dir.server, "server-icon-0.png"));
console.log(pathi);

const image = await resizeImg(pathi, {
     width: 64,
     height: 64,
});

fs.writeFileSync(path.join(this.props.dir.server, "server-icon.png"), image);
```

Logging `pathi` returns a `Buffer`.

```js
Buffer(77763)
```

It is an instance of a Uint8Array with apparently 77k+ numbers in it.

Running this code in a different project works. Is there something wrong with my code or my project?

Comment: what exact package do you use to resize images?

Comment: @Anatoly I use resize-img. ```npm install resize-img```

Comment: They use `Buffer.isBuffer(buffer)` as a check. Can you try it manually on `pathi`?

Comment: ```Buffer.isBuffer(pathi)``` returns false! How could this be? ```fs.readFileSync()``` should return a Buffer! It does outside of this project on others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer with help from [Anatoly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376618/anatoly).

Checking if `pathi` really was an instance of `Buffer` with `Buffer.isBuffer(pathi)` returned false. After constructing a new Buffer with `Buffer(pathi)` `Buffer.isBuffer(Buffer(pathi))` returned true!